# React custom hooks showing undefined error in Axios

Tags: reactjs

I have a cutom hook created as below. It is using axios and useEffect().

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
const baseURL="http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/test_server/"

const useAxios = ({ url, method='get', body = null, headers = JSON.stringify({ accept: '*/*' }),
}) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

    const fetchData = () => {
        axios[method](baseURL+url, JSON.parse(headers), JSON.parse(body))
            .then((res) => {
                setResponse(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setloading(false);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [method, url, body, headers]);

    return { response, error, loading };
};

export default useAxios;
```

I'm using this hook in another component as

```
const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState();
const { playerResponse, playerError, playerLoading} = useAxios({ url: 'player/get_player'})

if (playerResponse !== null ) {
      setPlayerData(playerResponse.result);
      console.log("Response", playerData);
    }
```

Everything seems correct but the code is showing `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result')`. Why this is happening?

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava

Comment: undefined !== null => true, so `if` is not really correct. But overall the error is due to  `{ playerResponse, playerError, playerLoading}` - if you export an object - you need to destructure respecting the names of the keys of this object. So if you change `playerResponse` to `response` and the rest - it should work.

Comment: Not showing undefined error now but another error `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` I'm using dependency array, still why the infinite loop problem?

Comment: @Sergey Sosunov

Comment: I honestly have no idea, need to see the full component code. But you can easilly debug it by commenting out suspicious parts of your code and checking if the error is gone. Also, im curious why your `if` is not inside of its own `useEffect`, also might be a problem, if you have a lot of things like this one.

Comment: The component is just rendering `hello world` for now. Some states are causing the infinite loop.

Comment: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` for this error the cause is most probably updating a state inside a `useEffect` and the same state value is using inside the same `useEffect` while the state is also included in the `dependancy array`